# How to delete a viewcontroller from a split view controller (ipad back button )?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, back

I have used the following code for deleting my login page from the `navigationcontroller(viewcontrollers)` so that it will not come into the view again when going back(back button).

```
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
{
NSMutableArray *VCs = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: self.navigationController.viewControllers];
   if ([[VCs objectAtIndex:[VCs count] - 2] isKindOfClass:[loginViewController class]]&&(VCs.count>=4))

   { [VCs removeObjectAtIndex:[VCs count] - 2];
   [VCs removeObjectAtIndex:[VCs count] - 2];
   [self.navigationController setViewControllers: VCs];
 }
NSLog(@" after :%@",VCs);
}
```

This works perfectly for i phone.I tried the following code for ipad

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {

NSMutableArray *VCs = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: self.splitViewController.viewControllers];
    NSLog(@" bofore :%@",VCs);
    if ([[VCs objectAtIndex:[VCs count] - 2] isKindOfClass:[loginViewController class]]&&(VCs.count>=4))
    {

        [VCs removeObjectAtIndex:[VCs count] - 2];
        [VCs removeObjectAtIndex:[VCs count] - 2];

        [self.navigationController setViewControllers: VCs];
        NSLog(@" after :%@",VCs);

    }

}
```

but The content of mutable array VCs in this case is `UINavigationControllar` objects.
Anyone know how to do the same this for ipad??Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In iPhone,
    NSMutableArray *VCs = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: self.navigationController.viewControllers];
Root controller is a navigation controller and so with above statement you would get View Controllers in its stack.

In iPad,
NSMutableArray *VCs = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: self.splitViewController.viewControllers];
Root controller is a splitviewcontroller which holds the stack of navigation controllers and so you get Navigation Controllers in the array.
Add below lines of your code and use ViewControllers Array to extract your own viewcontroller.

```
UINavigationController *navContoller = self.splitViewController.viewControllers[0]; // Get the Navigation Controller
NSMutableArray *viewControllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: navController.viewControllers];
```

Comment: ,Thanks for the answer.but,the NSMutableArray viewControllers  now contains a view controller and another UINavigationControllar object.Also self.splitViewController.viewControllers[0]; gives the MasterViewController.I used index 1 to get the detailViewConteroller.Do you know how this issue can be resolved.